# What is the cover of the Ender's Game depicting?

Tags: books, enders-game, cover-art

I'm asking about the main cover used by the novel (found on most of the 1985 and 1991 editions), **not** about the movie tie-in cover.

The four individual items that I notice:

1. The planet (Earth? Bugger home planet? Ender's World?)
2. Big artificial satellite (Battle School? Eros? Something else?)
3. Small, yellow ship. (Shuttle to/from battle school? Fighter in third invasion? Colony ship?)
4. Dots in space (ships? coordinates?)

Any ideas? Is it even one scene or is it just several stuff collaged together?

[image: Ender's Game cover]

Comment: @phantom42 It's a completely different question, but the answer is the same.

Comment: Yes, and [we define duplicates on questions OR answers.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6945/5184)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cover picture is a ripoff from the cover of the book *Drunkard's Walk* by Frederick Pohl:

[image: pohl cover]

The artwork is by the artist John Harris, and its title is also *Drunkard's Walk*. It appears on Harris's website [here](http://www.alisoneldred.com/imageJohnHarris-Books-0-425.html); see also [here](http://blog.endernews.com/2012/06/enders-game-cover-art-famous.html). So it's unlikely that the items in the picture are meant to denote anything from *Ender's Game*, maybe not even anything specific - it's probably just intended as a generic 'scifi' scene.

Here's the picture on its own, not as the cover of any book:

[image: picture]

Comment: Wow, I love how the stolen graphic matches perfectly the "Author's definitive edition" sign.

Comment: @DVK Beat you to this one :-)

Comment: @randal'thor - the question is IIRC a duplicate.

Comment: @DVK So I discovered after posting this answer. I've refrained from VTCing since apparently doing so would get me disapproval and downvotes on my answer.